# How to recursively reload a nextJS page and show an error page at the end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to recursively reload a page using the following util function:

```
export const refreshPage = (count)=>{
if (count <= 0){
    // window.location.reload();
    
    console.log("blue");
    return 
}else {
console.log("refreshing", count);
(typeof window !== 'undefined') && window.location.reload(true);
count--;
refreshPage(count)
}}
```

The function runs, but skips the window.location.reload() function each time, only reloading the page after console.log("blue"). The output looks like:

> refreshing 2
> refreshing 1
> blue

Then it refreshes. This causes the page to keep refreshing indefinitely. The nextJS project runs on the serverside so that might explain the behaviour.
The expected behaviour is to attempt to refresh the page twice, then redirect to an error page if another condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

It skips because `window` is `undefined`. If you wanna use it in a component, if you execute the function inside `useEffect()` or `componentDidMount()`, then when component is mounted, the `window` object wouldn't be `undefined`.

Comment: Trying this now... I'll provide feedback as soon as I have tested. @A. Azarfar